# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'topleft' of undefined on ngx-leaflet and esri-leaflet-geocoder

Tags: angular, leaflet, geocoding, esri, ngx-leaflet

I'm using `@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet` and `@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-draw` for leaflet map in my Angular 9 project. I tried a add search option in the map by 'esri-leaflet-geocoder'. without `@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet` and `@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-draw` using I am successfully place the search option in the map with no error. that works totally fine. here is my working code:

```js
/*npm install esri-leaflet esri-leaflet-geocoder*/
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import * as esriGeo from 'esri-leaflet-geocoder';

export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  public searchControl = new esriGeo.Geosearch();
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.initMap();        // not all codes are here;
    this.tiles.addTo(L.map);   // not all codes are here;
    
    this.searchControl.addTo(L.map);
  }
}
```

**Output Images:** [image: Working Output 1]
[image: Working Output 2]

But when I try to implement this same code where `@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet` and `@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-draw` were done previously, it says some error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'topleft' of undefined` .
**Error Output image:** [image]

Comment: L.map is not the instance of the map. It's a reference to the map constructor. Use ngx-leaflet and follow the directions to create and configure a map. Then, follow the directions to get a reference to the map, create your control and add it to that reference to the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the problem. Though I am using `ngx-leaflet` so here `L.Map` is not the current instance of the map. The `ngx-leaflet` initialize the map from the `LeafletDirective`. so the working code is:

```js
/*npm install esri-leaflet esri-leaflet-geocoder*/
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import * as esriGeo from 'esri-leaflet-geocoder';
import { LeafletDirective } from '@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet'; //new import

export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  public searchControl = new esriGeo.Geosearch();
  
  ngOnInit() {
    const map = this.leafletDirective.getMap(); // initialize map
    
    this.searchControl.addTo(map);
  }
}
```